# I have tried to install Flutter for hours but failed. PLease tell me how to solve this

Tags: java, flutter, android-studio, installation

I have
Install Andriod Studio and Java. This is the current issue.
I can't do anything. A similar error was posted and confused me futher

```
  flutter doctor
    Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.685], locale th-TH)
    [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
        X Android license status unknown.
          Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
          See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [!] Android Studio (not installed)
    [√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.

C:\Users\asus>flutter doctor --android-licenses
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSchema
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule$SchemaModuleVersion.<init>(SchemaModule.java:156)
        at com.android.repository.api.SchemaModule.<init>(SchemaModule.java:75)
        at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.<clinit>(AndroidSdkHandler.java:81)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:73)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:48)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:636)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:182)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:519)
        ... 5 more
```

Comment: The title should be updated to reflect issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Downloading the Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest) on Android Studio, under settings > Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools and re-running flutter doctor --android-licenses

[image: Android SDK path on Android Studio]

[image: Command-line Tools]